# Inserting zeroes - is this map continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The map $[0,1) \to [0,1)$ which inserts a $0$ between every decimal, e.g. $0.1234567\ldots \mapsto 0.010203040506070\ldots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not, because the sequence
$$\begin{gather}
0.09, \\
0.099, \\
0.0999, \\
0.09999, \\
\vdots 
\end{gather}$$ converges to $0.1$, while the sequence
$$\begin{align}
f(0.09) &= 0.0009, \\
f(0.099) &= 0.000909, \\
f(0.0999) &= 0.00090909, \\
&\,\,\,\vdots
\end{align}$$
converges to $0.00\overline{09} \neq 0.01 = f(0.1)$.